# Azure yml error when running ci/cd pipeline with test containers

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure-devops, rabbitmq, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up my first azure-pipelines.yml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/BookyWooks.sln' 
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    
# Add step to run tests
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'  # Specify test project(s) or wildcard pattern
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

However I am getting error:
[image]

The tests are passing locally but I have a connection issue when trying to run them in the pipeline. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

@AlvinZhao this is how I have set it up the test containers. I am using both sql server and rabbitmq:

```
public class OrderApiApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime where TEntryPoint : Program // : WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime
{
    private const string Database = "master";
    private const string Username = "sa";
    private const string Password = "yourStrong(!)Password";
    private string ConnectionString;
    private const ushort MsSqlPort = 1433;
    private const ushort RabbitMqPort = 5672; // RabbitMQ default port
    private readonly IContainer _mssqlContainer;
    private readonly IContainer _rabbitMqContainer;

public HttpClient HttpClient { get; private set; } = default!;

private const string RabbitMqUsername = "guest";
private const string RabbitMqPassword = "guest";

public OrderApiApplicationFactory()
{
    _mssqlContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
        .WithPortBinding(MsSqlPort, true)
        .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y") 
        .WithEnvironment("SQLCMDUSER", Username)
        .WithEnvironment("SQLCMDPASSWORD", Password)
        .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD", Password)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(MsSqlPort))
        .Build();

    _rabbitMqContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithImage("rabbitmq:3-management-alpine") // Use rabbitmq:management image
        .WithPortBinding(RabbitMqPort, 5672)
        .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER", RabbitMqUsername)
        .WithEnvironment("RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS", RabbitMqPassword)
        .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(RabbitMqPort)) // Adding wait strategy
        .Build();
}

public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await _mssqlContainer.StartAsync();
    await _rabbitMqContainer.StartAsync();

    var host = _mssqlContainer.Hostname;
    var port = _mssqlContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(MsSqlPort);

    ConnectionString = GetDatabaseConnectionString(); //$"Server={host},{port};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};TrustServerCertificate=True";

    //_respawner = await CreateRespawnerAsync();
    HttpClient = CreateClient();
}

protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        RemoveDbContextOptions<BookyWooksOrderDbContext>(services);
        RemoveDbContextOptions<IntegrationEventLogDbContext>(services);

        AddDbContext<BookyWooksOrderDbContext>(services);
        AddDbContext<IntegrationEventLogDbContext>(services);
    });
}

private void RemoveDbContextOptions<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : DbContext
{
    var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
        d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<T>));

    if (descriptor != null)
        services.Remove(descriptor);
}

private void AddDbContext<T>(IServiceCollection services) where T : DbContext
{
    services.AddDbContext<T>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString,
            builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(T).Assembly.FullName));
    });
}
private string GetDatabaseConnectionString()
{
    return $"Server={_mssqlContainer.Hostname},{_mssqlContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(MsSqlPort)};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};TrustServerCertificate=True";
}

public new async Task DisposeAsync()
{
    await _mssqlContainer.DisposeAsync();
    await _rabbitMqContainer.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of your YAML pipeline, the `dotnet test` command was running on `ubuntu-latest` Microsoft-hosted agents. You mentioned the tests were passing locally , it seems your tests requires connection to your SQL server. If your SQL server is behind a firewall, the tests may face such issue in connection with your SQL server. You may configure your SQL firewall to allow access from [possible IP ranges for Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents).

If your network policy restricts the access from MS-hosted agents and since your local environment will not incur the connection issue, you may configure [Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops) in your local environment and test to run your pipeline in this self-hosted agent pool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlvinZhao, but i think i incorrectly described my issue when i said my tests are passing locally. What I meant was I am using test containers for the tests and when I run them locally my containers are being spun up in docker and the tests are passing. However they are failing in my pipeline. Could what you have suggested still fix this?

Comment: Hi @Ports, Thanks for the update. May I know if your tests in container require connection to SQL server, since the error reports a connection issue right? If yes, is the SQL server accessible from any public network?

Comment: I made an update to the original post to show how I have set up the test containers. How can I tell if the SQL Server is accesible from any public network? I am having the same issue connection to RabbitMq

Comment: Hi Ports, I am afraid that I am not more famaliar than you about how your SQL/RabbitMq is configured. Besides, you are reaching out to the subcommunity of `Azure DevOps`; from the perspective of  Azure DevOps, you may test to use a self-hosted agent to run this pipeline and see if the issue is reproducible to narrow down the root cause. You can edit the tags of your orignial post to engage the experts' insights from `SQL` and `RabbitMq`.